# Java Guessing game 'might not be initialized'

Tags: java

I really need help with this. Im using BlueJ and it says 'might not be initialized'. How do i fix it? its **correctNumber** roughly line 16ish.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class NumberGuessingGame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int correctNumber; 
        int guessTracker;
        int guessLimit = 6; //the number of tries
        int userInput;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int game = 1;
        boolean winTracker = false;

        while (1 == game)
               correctNumber  = randomNumber.nextInt(1100); //computer generates a random number, max 100
               userInput = 0;
               guessTracker = 0;


             System.out.println("Hello and welcome to this number guessing game. Please guess the number between 1 and 100 and I will help you by telling you if your guess is too high or low: ");
        while (**correctNumber** != userInput && guessTracker < guessLimit){
                 userInput = in.nextInt();
                 guessTracker++;  


         if (userInput == correctNumber){
            System.out.println("You have won the game! Your reward is a fact game: Did you know the first working camera was invented in 1816! "); //winner message, with a unlocked fact game
            System.out.println("The correct number was " + correctNumber); //the correct number
            System.out.println("It took a total of " + guessTracker + " guesses"); //number of guesses it took the user to guess the right number.


        }

              else if (userInput < correctNumber){
                                   System.out.println("Your number is too low"); //displays that the users guess is too low
                         System.out.println("Please enter your next guess: "); //// user can now eneter their next guess
                      }

                else if (userInput > correctNumber){
            System.out.println("Your number is too high"); //displays that the users guess is too high
            System.out.println("Please enter your next guess: "); // user can now eneter their next guess
            }


        if (correctNumber != userInput){
            System.out.println("Sorry you have run out of guesses! The correct number was: " + correctNumber); // displays the correct number


        }

       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remember, Java is to JavaScript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. Please figure out the language you're writing code in.

Comment: Initialise your local variables to an initial value - it will at least get rid of the warning

Comment: Indentation is irrelevant. You need `{ }` to mark blocks of code. Of course, proper indentation makes the code readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize correctNumber to a value.

This is not always the case, but think about this:

you call `while(1 == game)` which then initialized correctNumber to a random number, `correctNumber  = randomNumber.nextInt(1100)` this would initialize correctNumber, but when the java compiler compiles your application it can't be sure that `1 == game` is true. Therefore, when the compiler gets to the next loop `while (**correctNumber** != userInput && guessTracker < guessLimit)` your compiler sees that correctNumber has not been initialized even though it would be by the first loop.

In short, the compiler does not know whether a loop will be entered or not, therefore user3437460 is absoultely correct in saying that you need to initialize local scope variables, in this case `int correctNumber = 0` will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I really need help with this. Im using BlueJ and it says 'might not be initialized'. How do i fix it?

Local scope variables need to be initialized (assigned an initial value) before use:

```
int correctNumber = 0
```

Same applies for your other variables.